# Solve Poisson problem $ \Delta u(\rho,\phi)=\ln \rho+2\cos^2\phi$ on annulus $1<\rho<3.$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, poissons-equation

Solve

\begin{eqnarray}
\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
\Delta u(\rho,\phi)=\ln \rho+2\cos^2\phi&,~ 1<r<3,~0\leqslant \phi \leqslant \pi,~0\leqslant \phi < 2\pi\\
\displaystyle u_{\rho}(1,\phi)=0,~~u(e,\phi)=\cos(2\phi)&,~0\leqslant \phi< 2\pi\\
\end{array}
\right..
\end{eqnarray}

*Attempt.* Writing $\ln \rho+2\cos^2\phi=\ln \rho+1+\cos(2\phi)$ we seek one solution of the form $w_1(\rho)$ such that $w_1''+\frac{1}{\rho}\,w_1'=\ln \rho+1$ and one solution
the form $w_2(\rho,\phi)$ such that $\Delta w_2=\cos(2\phi)$. Then
$v=u-w_1-w_2$ solves the Laplace equation:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left \{\begin {array}{lll}
\Delta v(\rho,\phi)= 0&,~ 1<r<3,~0\leqslant \phi \leqslant \pi,~0\leqslant \phi < 2\pi\\
\displaystyle v_{\rho}(1,\phi)=-w_1'(1)-(w_2)_{\rho}(1,\phi),\\
v(e,\phi)=\cos(2\phi)-w_1(e)-w_2(e,\phi)&,~0\leqslant \phi< 2\pi\\
\end{array}
\right..
\end{eqnarray}

The problem of $w_1$ is relatively easy: one solution is $\rho^2\ln \rho/4$. For the other part of $w_2$, i can't seem to find any obvious solution (candidate $r^2\cos(2\phi)$ solve solves the homogenuous problem, of course).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: $w_2=\frac{1}{4}\rho^2(\ln\rho)\cos(2\phi)$.